# $I=mI$, when I is not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a commutative local ring with unit. Suppose $I$ is an ideal (not finitely generated). If $I=mI$, what can we say about $I$? Can we conclude something interesting?

If $I$ were finitely generated, then Nakayama's lemma would imply $I=0$, so I am interested in the case when $I$ is not finitely generated.

Any reference would be appreciated. Thanks

I asked this question on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873693/i-mi-when-i-is-not-finitely-generated).

Comment: Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $2$ and $R=\bigcup^{\infty} k[[x^{1/2^i}]]$. Then the unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ is generated by $\{x^{1/2^i}:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$. It is easily seen that $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$. In general if $R$ is a perfect ring of prime characteristic $p>0$ then any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ satisfies $\mathfrak{p}^2=\mathfrak{p}$, whence $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{p}$, provided $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is local as well.

Comment: There are lots of nonnoetherian local rings with idempotent maximal ideal.  Just take any valuation ring with value group $G=G_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus G_n$ in lexicographic order, where each $G_i$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ and $G_1$ is 2-divisible, in the sense that for any $x\in G_1$, we also have $x/2 \in G_1$.  Aurora's comment is a special case of this, where $n=1$ and $G=G_1=\mathbb Z[1/2]$.